# underscore.js filter function

Tags: backbone.js, filtering, underscore.js

I'm attempting to learn backbone.js and (by extension) underscore.js, and I'm having some difficulty understanding some of the conventions. While writing a simpel search filter, I thought that something like below would work:

```
var search_string = new RegExp(query, "i");

        var results = _.filter(this, function(data){
            return search_string.test(data.get("title"));
        }));
```

But, in fact, for this to work I need to change my filter function to the following:

```
var search_string = new RegExp(query, "i");

        var results = _(this.filter(function(data){
            return search_string.test(data.get("title"));
        }));
```

Basically, I want to understand why the second example works, while the first doesn't. Based on the documentation (http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter) I thought that the former would have worked. Or maybe this just reflects some old jQuery habits of mine... Can anyone explain this for me?

Comment: It should read _.filter -- sorry that was a typo. With _.filter data is empty, and, as a result, "results" returns an empty array.

Comment: And `this` is a Backbone collection?

Comment: Yeah, it is. A console.log of (this) provides me a "child" with length, models, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess that you're using a browser with a native [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) implementation. Try these in your console and see what happens:

```
[].filter.call({ a: 'b' }, function(x) { console.log(x) });
[].filter.call([1, 2],     function(x) { console.log(x) });
```

The first one won't do anything, the second will produce `1` and `2` as output (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tkRQ3/). The problem isn't that `data` is empty, the problem is that the native `Array#filter` doesn't know what to do when applied to non-Array object.

All of Underscore's methods (including [`filter`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter)) use the native implementations if available:

> Delegates to the native **filter** method, if it exists.

So the Array-ish Underscore methods generally won't work as `_.m(collection, ...)` unless you're using a browser that doesn't provide native implementations.

A Backbone collection is a wrapper for an array of models, the models array is in `c.models` so you'd want to:

```
_.filter(this.models, function(data) { ... });
```

Backbone [collections have several Underscore methods](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) mixed in:

> Backbone proxies to **Underscore.js** to provide 28 iteration functions on **Backbone.Collection**.

and one of those is `filter`. These proxies apply the Underscore method to the collection's model array so `c.filter(...)` is the same as `_.filter(c.models, ...)`.

This mixing-in is probably what's confusing the ["should I use the native method"](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L153) checks that Underscore is doing:

```
if (nativeFilter && obj.filter === nativeFilter) return obj.filter(iterator, context);
```

You can use `_.filter` on a plain old object (`_.filter({a:'b'}, ...)`) and get sensible results but it fails when you `_.filter(backbone_collection, ...)` because collections already have Underscore methods.

Here's a simple demo to hopefully clarify things: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FHd3Y/1/

Answer (score -1):

For the same reason that `$('#element')` works and `$#element` doesn't. `_` is the global variable for the underscore object just like `$` is the global variable for the `jQuery` object.

`_()` says look in the `_` object. `_filter` says look for a method named `_filter`.